# Open up Google map marker from link outside of the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How can I open up a map marker info window from a link outside of the map?

I've figured out how to open up the info window by clicking on the marker within the map with the following code:

```
GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    marker.openInfoWindowHtml("<div>I'm a marker</div>");
});
```

However, I cannot figure out how to get it to work from a link outside of the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely you have more than one marker. Kill two birds with one stone and put them into a global array:

```
var markers = []

GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    marker[i].openInfoWindowHtml("<div>I'm a marker</div>");
});
```

Then you can simply call this, where the value of **i** is the index position of the marker:

```
marker[i].openInfoWindowHtml(...your html...);
```